# how to download wine offline

Tags: wine

I just installed Ubuntu on my desktop via a Youtube tutorial, they forgot to mention that Linux doesn't support Windows exe files. I cannot access the wired internet in my room, in order to download this file called 'wine'. I'm using the student centre wifi with my laptop, tried downloading the file, I just don't understand what needs to be done. Thanks

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: The official web site of Wine.

Comment: You might already have [equivalent software installed](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Linux_software_equivalent_to_Windows_software) so no need to use wine at all...

Answer (score 3):

First, download the .deb files.

You get .deb files of Wine here:

[Download site](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+packages)

Use the filter on the page and set it so that it shows only packages for the version of Ubuntu your attempting to install.

If you need any dependent .deb files search for them, and download which ones you need at:

[Search and download site](http://packages.ubuntu.com)

Save them to flash drive.

To install it on your desktop pc, run:

```
sudo -i
cd /media/user/flash_drive/
dpkg -i *.deb
```